# Given a javascript array and one of its members, how to retrieve the member index?

Tags: javascript

Given a javascript array and one of its members, how to retrieve the member index without having to compare the contents of the member against every other member in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `indexOf`, like this:

```
var index = someArray.indexOf(value);
```

Since IE doesn't have `indexOf`, you'll need to make it yourself:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/) {
        var len = this.length >>> 0;

        var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
        from = (from < 0) ? Math.ceil(from) : Math.floor(from);

        if (from < 0)
            from += len;

        for (; from < len; from++) {
            if (from in this && this[from] === elt)
                return from;
        }
        return -1;
    };
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be lastIndexOf?

Comment: Here is the FF implementation of indexOf method https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility

Comment: your `indexOf` implementation is lacking. Have a look at the one linked to by Amarghosh.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
// The following line returns the zero-based index of 'c'
array.indexOf('c'); // 2
// If the element is not found in the array, -1 is returned:
array.indexOf('z'); // -1
```

Sadly, `Array#indexOf` is not natively supported in Internet Explorer. See SLaks’s answer for a working fallback!

Answer (score 0):

Consider Objx for working with Arrays http://code.google.com/p/objx/wiki/Plugins